# Triangle ratio problem - any other methods other than mass point geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

In the given triangle, the following side-length ratios are known,

$$AE ∶ EB = 3 ∶ 4,\>\>\> BD ∶ DC = 5 ∶ 6,\>\>\> AF ∶ FC = 2 ∶ 3$$

Then find the ratio AO ∶ OD.

I can solve it by mass point geometry but i want to know if there is any other method available. MpG feels like finding center of mass in physics, unlike rigorous mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Denote various areas as $[\cdot]$ and use area ratios below to evaluate

\begin{align}
\frac{AO}{OD} =& \ \frac{[AEF]}{[EDF]}
= \frac{[AEF]}{[EBCF]-[FDC]-[EBD]}\\
= &\ \frac{\frac 25 \frac 37 [ABC]}
{\left( 1-\frac 25 \frac 37 \right)[ABC] - \frac 35 \frac{6}{11}[ABC] - \frac 47 \frac{5}{11}[ABC]} \\
= &\ \frac{\frac{6}{35}}
{\frac{25}{35} - \frac{18}{55} - \frac{20}{77}}=\frac{22}{31} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method using similar triangles, which may be a more familiar concept to the OP.  In the triangle $ABC$, draw lines $BG$ and $DH$ parallel to $EF$, to intersect $AC$ at $G$ and $H$ respectively, as shown in the diagram below.

We have $\ AF = \frac{2}{5}AC\ $, and therefore
$$
FG = \frac{4}{3}AF = \frac{8}{15}AC
$$
by the similarity of triangles $AEF$ and $ABG$. Then $GC= AC-AG$$=\frac{1}{15}AC$, and
$$
GH = \frac{5}{11}GC = \frac{1}{33}AC
$$
from the similarity of triangles $CBG$ and $CDH$.  Now from the similarity of triangles $AOF$ and $ADH$  we get
$$
AO:OD = AF:FH = \frac{2}{5}:\left(\frac{8}{15}+\frac{1}{33}\right)=22:31\ .
$$

[image: triangle with BG & DH added]

Answer (score 1):

I’ll provide a simple solution involving the Menelaus’ Theorem (with non-signed lengths): [image]

Extend $EF$ to meet $CB$ extended at M.

Given $\dfrac {BD}{DC}=\dfrac56$, let $BD=5X, DC=6X$ and let $MB=uX$. Then by Menelaus in $\triangle ABC$, $$\frac{MC}{MB}\cdot \frac{BE}{EA}\cdot \frac{AF}{FC}=1$$ so that $$\frac{u+5+6}{u}\cdot \frac43\cdot \frac23=1$$ so we find that $u=88$.

Again by Menelaus in $\triangle ABD$, $$\frac{MD}{MB}\cdot \frac{BE}{EA}\cdot \frac{AO}{OD}=1$$ so

$$\frac{u+5}{u}\cdot \frac43\cdot \frac{AO}{OD}=1$$
or $$\frac{93}{88}\cdot \frac43\cdot \frac{AO}{OD}=1$$ or $$\frac{AO}{OD}=\frac{22}{31}.$$